# How to apply a global query on the distibuted database tables that I have created

Tags: sql, database, distributed-database

I have created 4 tables(`Mumbai, Bangalore, Pune, Delhi`) with customer information

In all 4 tables, I have a bill amount table column in my table, I want to display the sum of bill Amounts of all tables from Highest to lowest.

I have used the following query, but I don’t know how to go ahead with it.

Create view view1 as:

```
Select sum(m.BillAmount),sum(p.BillAmount),sum(b.BillAmount),sum(c.BillAmount)
from Mumbai m,Chennai c, Pune p, Bangalore b 
ORDER BY
```

Please can I get appropriate queries related to this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a design issue here. You should have only one table to store all your cities. You have now 4 cities, but if tour client wants to add another, with your current design you will have to add a table and change your sql queries.

If you create a table for your cities and another for your bills with a foreign key referencing the cities, you will be able to get the sum of your bills for all of your cities.

```
Table cities
------------------
id     city_name
1      Mumbai
2      Bengalore
3      Pune
4      Delhi
-------------------

Table bills
--------------------
id   city_id  amount
1       1      100
2       1      100
3       2      100
4       3      100
5       4      100
6       3      100
7       1      100
```

Here is the query

```
SELECT c.city_name, SUM(b.amount) as total
FROM bills as b INNER JOIN cities as c
    ON c.id = b.city_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: Tried this query but it's giving me an error (not a group by expression)

Comment: With some SQL implementations you can only use one of your SELECT columns in a GROUP BY. So in your case I suggest that you replace GROUP BY c.id by GROUP BY c.city_name